# console.log(object) works, trying to access a property from object returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, object, properties

Here is how the object is set :

```html
const Product = () => {

  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/"+id);
        setProduct(res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    getProduct()
  }, [id]);
```

when I console.log(product) I get the object return with all the properties:

```html
product: Object { _id: "812389123981278", title: "Lalalala", description: "desc here", … }
​​
__v: 0
​​
_id: "98123789128793"
​​
categories: Array(3) [ "Protein", "Supplements", "Apparel" ]
​​
createdAt: "2022-02-12T22:46:46.138Z"
​​
description: "desc here"
​​
img: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LazarVell/irongrip/main/src/images/optimumnutritionisolate.webp"
​​
inStock: true
​​
price: 50
​​
size: Array [ "L" ]
​​
title: "Optimum Nutrition Gold Standard Isolate"
​​
types: Array [ "Protein" ]
​​
updatedAt: "2022-02-12T22:46:46.138Z"
```

I am trying to get the properties to pass into my React component.

```html
  return (
        <Container>
          <Navbar/>
          <Wrapper>
            <ImgContainer>
            <Image src={product.img} />
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
              <Title>{product.title}</Title>
              <Description>{product.description}</Description>
              <Price> {product.price}</Price>
```

I can't extract any of these properties, they always return undefined. What am I doing wrong here? The object itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`product` is just a blank object before you call from the API using `useEffect`. You render the component while the object has no properties, so it errors when you access nested properties. You could have a loading component that shows while `product` is still a blank object with no properties, and renders `product` when it is not a blank object.

`if (product === {}) return <Loading/>`

`return ()` <- react component code here

You can also make a new state called loading, have it be a boolean, and have it change to true after the component gets the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I was able to delay the rendering until axios completes the request, but it still returns undefined. I made a new state to hold the render until it loads.
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
...
    getProduct();
    setLoading(false);
...
 if (loading) { 
    return (<div>Loading...</div>)
  }
...
the rest of the return render, It didn't work sadly

Comment: @LazarVell I think you need to use .then, and then call setLoading(false). You could also add setLoading(false) to the end of getProduct.

Comment: I used getProduct().then(setLoading(false)); but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @LazarVell .then asks for a function not called with no arguments. You need to do `getProduct().then(() => setLoading(false))`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/"+id);
        setProduct(() => res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    if (!_.isEmpty(id)) { // _ is lodash, npm i lodash
      getProduct()
    }
  }, [id]);
```

Comment: Hey Lenam, thanks for the reply. I tried lodash but it didn't solve the issue. I Also managed to delay rendering until component loads but that didn't solve the issue either.